# Avoiding compiler warning 1998

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

We use a state machine that provides properties to define actions of type `Func<Task<bool>>` that indicate whether a state transition should be triggered.

What is the best way to set this (state machine) property to a property of type `bool`?

Currently we do it like this:

```
private void SetupStateMachine()
{
    StateMachine.NotRunningToCloseDoorsViaStart = async () => AreAllDoorsClosed;
}

private bool AreAllDoorsClosed => _doors.All(door => door.IsClosed);
```

But the compiler generates warning 1998 then. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just get rid of `async` keyword.

Comment: The method isn't async, and no tasks are involved, simply remove `async` keyword and you're good to go. To return a task from a method that doesn't really do async work, return `Task.CompletedTask` at the end. or `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: We added the `async` keyword to comply with the expected delegate type `Func<Task<bool>>`. My question was about a better way to achieve this. The `Task.FromResult` hits the spots. Thank you, @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that your method doesn't use `await`, which is the purpose of adding `async`, to allow this.

Since you're doing non-asynchronous code in this delegate, the correct response is to remove `async`, but I guess why you added it, the compiler will now complain that you're not returning a task.

To fix this, wrap the results in a task:

```
StateMachine.NotRunningToCloseDoorsViaStart = () => Task.FromResult(AreAllDoorsClosed);
```